# Linq join vs contains cast error

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am having an issue that is perplexing me to no end. I have two ways to compose on an existing linq query. One of which works.

Working:

```
var splitStatuses = context.Split(model.Statuses, "statuses");
query = query.Where(x => splitStatuses.Contains(x.statusFk));
```

Not Working:

```
query =
  from qry in query
  join status in context.Split(model.Statuses, "statuses") on qry.statusFk equals status
  select qry;
```

The query is calling a TVF and filtering results based off of the return. The non-working query works if I get count, but when I get data, I get a cast error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32()
```

Maybe some EF/linq wizard can shed some light onto why this is happening.

Comment: I'm just showing the snippet where I am composing on the larger query. To get count, it is doing a simple query.Count(). The contains translates into an exists clause in SQL, the other one is an inner join which performs much faster in our testing. The fact that EF is able to generate the SQL and successfully get the count tells me that the join way of doing it works, and then when I try to get data it blows up has me completely confused.

Comment: Is `Split` built into EF?

Comment: No, it is a table valued function wired in via https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.CodeFirstStoreFunctions/